# Pasar array/lista a función

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, funciones

Tengo que hacer un programa en el que el usuario inserte un polinomio y este salga su derivada y su integral.

Lo que llevo hasta ahora es que ya pude almacenar el polinomio, en un arreglo en el que cada coeficiente se almacena y su exponente lo consulto con la posición que tiene el coef en el arreglo.

El problema que tengo es que para integrar necesito usar la regla de Simpson y para esta, sólo he visto métodos que conlleven a usarla con una función, lo que da lugar a mi problema principal.

¿Cómo puedo pasar mi polinomio a una función para poder aplicar la regla de Simpson?

Adjunto parte de mi código por si es útil:

```
pol = []
dev = []

grado = int(input("Inserte grado del polinomio  ")

print("Favor de insertar coeficientes del polinomio empezando desde el menor hasta el mayor")
for i in range(grado+1):
    pol.append(int(input("Inserte siguiente coef -> ")))
print(pol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, quieres generar una función basándote en los coeficientes del polinomio. En definitiva, lo que necesitas es una función que devuelva la función polinómica:

```py
def mk_polinomio(pol):
    grado = len(pol)
    def f(x):
        return sum(pol[i] * x**i for i in range(grado))
    return f

f = mk_polinomio(pol)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, me parece que ya con esas lineas e sposible pasarlo a función, sin embargo me aparece un error al querer evaluar dicha funcion polinomica para poder aplicar la regla o metodo de simpson, te adjunto mi codigo para ver si me podrias ayudar por favor:(                                                  def simpson13(f,a,b):
    m=(a+b) / 2
    integral= (b - a) / 6 *(f(a) + 4 * f(m) + f(b))
    return integral 
n = 40
dx=(b - a) / n
suma = 0
for i in range(n):  
    b = a + dx
    area= simpson13(f, a, b)
    suma = suma + area
    a = b
 
print(suma)

Comment: Y el error que me aparece es este   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Tenía un pequeño error. Prueba de nuevo. Si es posible, edita la pregunta y añade el código que has puesto en el comentario para que sea más útil a quien busque preguntas similares.